# Enable table option in wordpress editor without using plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anybody tell me that how can I enable the option of table in wordpress editor?

I used below code which help me to enable other option, but not for the table.

### My function.php

```
  <?php

      function add_more_buttons($buttons) {
       $buttons[] = 'hr';
       $buttons[] = 'del';
       $buttons[] = 'sub';
       $buttons[] = 'sup';
       $buttons[] = 'fontselect';
       $buttons[] = 'fontsizeselect';
       $buttons[] = 'cleanup';
       $buttons[] = 'tablecontrols';
       return $buttons;
 }
 add_filter("mce_buttons_3", "add_more_buttons");

 ?>
```

Comment: WordPress doesn't ship with the table plugin for TinyMCE, you need to manually add the appropriate HTML, JS and CSS files or you can just [use this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-tinymce-tables/).

Comment: Do you get solution for your question ??

Answer (score 19):

**Without a Plugin**

You need to download the "table" folder from the TinyMCE editor package. The easiest way download it is to [use the TinyMCE version 4 Custom Build tool](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/custom-builds/). (WordPress doesn't use the latest version of TinyMCE, so you need the plugin built for version 4.) Uncheck everything except the "table" plugin.

Once you've downloaded it, unzip it and navigate to /tinymce/plugins and copy the "table" folder.

In this example, I'm copying it to a new folder called "tinymce-plugins" that I've created in my WordPress site's "wp-content" folder.

[image: Windows Explorer window showing the contents of "wp-content" with the sub-folder "tinymce-plugins" highlighted]

In your theme's function.php file, register the button and include the path to the JavaScript file:

```
function add_the_table_button( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'separator', 'table' );
    return $buttons;
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'add_the_table_button' );

function add_the_table_plugin( $plugins ) {
      $plugins['table'] = content_url() . '/tinymce-plugins/table/plugin.min.js';
      return $plugins;
}
add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'add_the_table_plugin' );
```

Then BOOM! The table functionality is activated.

[image: A screenshot of the TinyMCE editor toolbar with the table icon expanded, showing table inclusion and formatting options]

Comment: The TinyMCE website has completely changed... is there a way to go get that plugin now?

Comment: @Fredy31 the way is still the same. Download TinyMCE as a self-hosted release from [download page](https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/). You may also use their build customizer - uncheck all options and check only "table" addon.

Comment: When using this approach, I get the following Error in WP 5.6.3: `tinymce.min.js?ver=49110-20201110:2 Failed to initialize plugin: table TypeError: Cannot read property 'registry' of undefined`

Comment: @rassoh Wordpress is using Tİnymce version 4.9.11. So you need to change the Tinymce version that you downloaded. Do not use Tİnymce v5.

Comment: Yeah that still works - just replace the version in the current link - the link for the moment [is](https://download.tiny.cloud/tinymce/community/tinymce_4.9.11.zip).

Comment: It is not working for me. I download version 6.3.1 from the site. The function.php is on the theme folder? I using child them. I also want to add more buttons, is it possible?
I getting error “Failed to initialize plugin: table” on the editor
and on the console I getting: “Failed to initialize plugin: table TypeError: r is not a constructor”

Answer (score 0):

To enable table option in wordpress page editor you can use plugin like

1.**TablePress**

2.**TinyMCE**

install and activate plugin ,see documentation to how this works.

In TablePress you can create tables from dashboard and can include this in page or post from editor menu(insert table from TablePress) or can use shortcode too.
download link : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tablepress/

2TinyMCE

To display the full TinyMCE text editor so you have access to all of the advanced features available, add the following code to your functions.php file to enable hidden buttons:(below code is compatible with some of the new wordpress version only so try to use plugins itself).

```
function enable_more_buttons($buttons) {

$buttons[] = 'fontselect';
$buttons[] = 'fontsizeselect';
$buttons[] = 'styleselect';
$buttons[] = 'backcolor';
$buttons[] = 'newdocument';
$buttons[] = 'cut';
$buttons[] = 'copy';
$buttons[] = 'charmap';
$buttons[] = 'hr';
$buttons[] = 'visualaid';

return $buttons;

}
add_filter("mce_buttons_3", "enable_more_buttons”);
```

To keep the kitchen sink always on, also add this snippet to your functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'myformatTinyMCE' );
function myformatTinyMCE( $in ) {

$in['wordpress_adv_hidden'] = FALSE;

return $in;
}
```

download link ::TinyMCE Advanced :: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

Comment: Is that not possible without plugin?

Comment: why not but i think you need to write html, css and js for this.I just answer the easy method. it must help you to add tables in your pages or post through editor

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to enable table option in the Wordpress editor to use tables inside it.

You can just build your table with the `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` tags and paste the finale result inside the editor.